# Converting Source ASCII Files to JPEGs

Tags: html, imagemagick, jpeg, pretty-print

I publish technical books, in print, PDF, and Kindle/MOBI, with EPUB on the way.

The Kindle does not support monospace fonts, which are kinda useful for source code listings. The only way to do monospace fonts is to convert the text (Java source, HTML, XML, etc.) into JPEG images. More specifically, due to pagination issues, a given input ASCII file needs to be split into slices of ~6 lines each, with each slice turned into a JPEG, so listings can span a screen. This is a royal pain.

My current mechanism to do that involves:

1. Running `expand` to set a consistent 2-space tab size, which pipes to...
2. `a2ps`, which pipes to...
3. A small Perl snippet to add a `"%%LanguageLevel: 3\n"` line, which pipes to...
4. ImageMagick's `convert`, to take the (E)PS and make a JPEG out it, with an appropriate background, cropped to `575x148+5+28`, etc.

That used to work 100% of the time. It now works 95% of the time. The rest of the time, I get `convert: geometry does not contain image` errors, which I cannot seem to get rid of, in part because I don't understand what the problem is.

Before this process, I used to use a pretty-print engine (`source-highlight`) to get HTML out of the source code...but then the only thing I could find to convert the HTML into JPEGs was to automate screen-grabs from an embedded Gecko engine. Reliability stank, which is why I switched to my current mechanism.

So, if you were you, and you needed to turn source listings into JPEG images, in an automated fashion, how would you do it? Bonus points if it offers some sort of pretty-print process (e.g., bolded keywords)!

Or, if you know what typically causes `convert: geometry does not contain image`, that might help. My current process is ugly, but if I could get it back to 100% reliability, that'd be just fine for now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138804/how-to-transform-a-text-file-into-a-picture

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might consider html2ps and then imagemagick's convert.

A thought: if your target (Kindle?) supports PNG, use that in preference to JPEG for this text rendering.

Comment: That holds some promise. I'm pretty sure I went down that path before and abandoned it, but I forget why, and my preliminary tests suggest it may work out OK. I'll try to get this going tomorrow or Monday to confirm this solution works. Thanks!

Comment: No dice. Getting the same ImageMagick error at about the same frequency. Must be a Postscript input thing.

Comment: Actually, further experiments showed that the error only occurs, with the html2ps solution, when the source file had trailing whitespace that caused an effectively empty image to be created. So, this works! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

html2ps is an excellent program -- I used it to produce a 1300-page book once, but it's overkill if you just want plain text -> postscript.  Consider enscript instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because the question of converting HTML to JPG has been answered, I will offer a suggestion on the pretty printer. I've found [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) to be pretty awesome. It supports different themes and has lexers for pretty much any language out there (they advertise the fact that it even highlights [brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck)). There's a command line tool and it's available on most Linux distros.

Answer (score 0):

Your Linux distribution may include pango-view and an assortment of fonts.
This works on my FC6 system:

```
pango-view --font=DejaVuLGCSansMono --dpi=200 --output=/tmp/text.jpg -q /tmp/text
```

You'll need to identify a monospaced font that is installed on your system.  Look around `/usr/share/fonts/`.

Pango supports Unicode.

Leave off the -q while you're experimenting, it'll display to a window instead of to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use jpeg.  It's optimized for photographs and does a terrible job with text and line art.  Use gif or png instead.  My understanding is that gif is now patent-free, so I would just use that.

Comment: No option on Kindle -- JPEG or bust.